# How to: Download Driver

Tags: centos, filesystems, wget, curl

I would like to download this package

3.16 - 5.14     drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/os_dep/usb_intf.c     CONFIG_R8188EU CONFIG_STAGING   2357:010c   *

From here: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:2357-010c

I tried

> wget -c https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:2357-010c

> wget -c https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:2357-010c/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/os_dep/usb_intf.c

both were

> ERROR 403: Forbidden

Comment: These drivers are part of the Linux kernel staging tree. They are not in a package. What you link to is not a package, but merely an info website. Are you familiar with compiling the Linux kernel?

Comment: The link https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/staging/r8188eu/os_dep/usb_intf.c is just the link to source code mentioning the device. It's for reading and may be patching the code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known working driver on [github](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu).

You'll need to compile it according to the README.md.